# Oracle 12c - Find if temporary objects created before TEMP_UNDO_ENABLED is set

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

**Database** : Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2) - Enterprise Edition with RAC

I'm trying to reduce REDO and archive logs generated for my application and measure using V$SYSSTAT and corresponding archive logs using DBA_HIST* views.

In my application code on DB side, I'm using the session level setting of `TEMP_UNDO_ENABLED` to direct UNDO for gtt into temporary tablespace. The specific feature noted [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E2A01A84-2D63-401F-B64E-C96B18C5DCA6.htm#REFRN10326).

```
ALTER SESSION SET TEMP_UNDO_ENABLED = TRUE;
INSERT INTO my_gtt VALUES...
```

Note the documentation has this quote:

> ..if the session already has temporary objects using regular undo, setting this parameter will have no effect

If I use a pure database session, I can ascertain that since no other temporary tables have been created/used before setting the parameter, the REDO logs generated are minimal. I can use a simple (`select value from V$SYSSTAT where name= 'redo size'`) to see the difference.

However the actual application (Java) triggers this code through a JDBC session. As such, I'm unable to ascertain if before the call to '`ALTER SESSION..`' there were any GTT or other temporary objects previously created/used in the session. The consequence of this is, if say a GTT was already used, then the call to '`ALTER SESSION SET TEMP_UNDO_ENABLED = TRUE`' simply ignores the setting without an indication. The code will continue logging UNDO & REDO in the normal tablespace, which is unintended.

Is there any way to query if this parameter TEMP_UNDO_ENABLED is already set/unset within the session, so that before I do a `ALTER SESSION SET TEMP_UNDO_ENABLED = TRUE` I'll know for sure this will or will not have an effect?

Thanks in advance for inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no holistic way to do this satisfying all cases. Posting some options I got as answer elsewhere:

**Assumptions :**
Both options work only if:

- Only GTT is concerned (excluding WITH and other temporary objects)
- COMMIT/ROLLBACK has not already been done including from SAVEPOINTS
  or other methods

**Option 1** : Use v$tempseg_usage, to check if any segment created in DATA, instead of TEMP_UNDO

```
select count(*)
  from v$tempseg_usage
 where contents = 'TEMPORARY'
   and segtype = 'DATA'
   and session_addr =
       (select saddr
          from v$session
         where sid = sys_context('userenv', 'sid'));
```

**Option 2** : Use gv$transaction as below, ubafil = 0 if for temp_undo, else ubafil = undo tablespace file id:

```
select count(*)
  from gv$transaction
 where ses_addr = (select saddr
                     from v$session
                    where sid = sys_context('userenv', 'sid'))
   and ubafil <> 0;
```

On other note for thought, I still think, there should have been a parameter or an indication elsewhere that simply indicates the setting of TEMP_UNDO_ENABLED has not had an effect, within the scope of a SESSION, not having to touch views that would otherwise be considered as administrative.

I'm open to answers if someone finds a better approach.

Answer (score -1):

Although this does not answer your question directly but this [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables) may help you.

In 12c temporary undo concept has been added

> " Oracle 12c introduced the concept of Temporary Undo, allowing the
> undo for a GTT to be written to the temporary tablespace, thereby
> reducing undo and redo."

Comment: Atif, I did not downvote, but on this link I could not find where temp objects from the session can be queried before the ALTER SESSION. The feature part I'm already aware of.